# Why when saving a game it's writing the saved game only if I leave the editor window and then coming back?

Tags: unity, c#

It's not saving in runtime for some reason.  Only when I stop the game and only when leaving the editor window then when coming back to the editor window I see it's writing the saved game file on the hard drive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    private static readonly string SAVE_FOLDER = Application.dataPath + "/Saved Games";
    private static string content;

    public static void Init()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SAVE_FOLDER);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string saveString)
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(SAVE_FOLDER, "savegame.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, saveString);
    }

    public static void Save(string SaveString, string FolderToSave, string FileName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(FolderToSave))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderToSave);
        }

        string fileName = Path.Combine(FolderToSave, FileName);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, SaveString);
    }

    public static string Load()
    {
        content = "";
        string fileName = Path.Combine(SAVE_FOLDER, "savegame.txt");

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        return content;
    }

    public static string Load(string FolderToLoadFrom, string FileName)
    {
        content = "";
        string fileName = Path.Combine(FolderToLoadFrom, FileName);

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        return content;
    }
}
```

It should make the whole saving and writing the file in runtime.

Comment: The solution is when saving the file to the hard disk to use : AssetDatabase.Refresh();

Comment: Putting your savegames in `Application.dataPath` (the directory with your game assets) is a bad idea! On a lot of target platforms, that directory won't be writable. Use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead. It gives you the directory where you are supposed to store savegames according to what's the best practice on the user's operating system.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to refresh the Assets data base when writing the file to the hard disk :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    private static readonly string SAVE_FOLDER = Application.dataPath + "/Saved Games";
    private static string content;

    public static void Init()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(SAVE_FOLDER))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(SAVE_FOLDER);
        }
    }

    public static void Save(string saveString)
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(SAVE_FOLDER, "savegame.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, saveString);

        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    public static void Save(string SaveString, string FolderToSave, string FileName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(FolderToSave))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderToSave);
        }

        string fileName = Path.Combine(FolderToSave, FileName);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, SaveString);

        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }

    public static string Load()
    {
        content = "";
        string fileName = Path.Combine(SAVE_FOLDER, "savegame.txt");

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        return content;
    }

    public static string Load(string FolderToLoadFrom, string FileName)
    {
        content = "";
        string fileName = Path.Combine(FolderToLoadFrom, FileName);

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        return content;
    }
}
```

This line did the trick :

```
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

Comment: Have you tried building the game after making this change?